# React state variable updates automatically without calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I am facing the following issue and not able to figure it out.

I have two variables inside the state called userDetails & userDetailsCopy. In componentDidMount I am making an API call and saving the data in both userDetails & userDetailsCopy.

I am maintaining another copy called userDetailsCopy for comparison purposes.

I am updating only userDetails inside setState but even userDetailsCopy is also getting updated instead of have old API data.

Below is the code :

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
        userDetails:{},
        userDetailsCopy: {}
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
     // API will return the following data
       apiUserDetails : [
            {
                 'name':'Tom',
                 'age' : '28'
            },
            {
                 'name':'Jerry',
                 'age' : '20'

            }
        ]

       resp.data is nothing but apiUserDetails
    /////

     apiCall()
     .then((reps) => {
         this.setState({ 
             userDetails: resp.data,
             userDetailsCopy: resp.data
         })
     })
}

updateValue = (text,i) => {
     let userDetail = this.state.userDetails
     userDetail[i].name = text
     this.setState({ 
         userDetails: userDetail
     })
}

submit = () => {
     console.log(this.state.userDetials) // returns updated values
     console.log(this.state.userDetailsCopy) // also return updated values instead of returning old API data
}

Need a quick solution on this.
```

Comment: `userDetails.name = text` this mutates the current state object, which is probably why you see changes on both the `userDetails` and `userDetailsCopy` objects.

Comment: where have you set userDetailsCopy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Comment: And here's [why you shouldn't mutate the current state object.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Comment: And here's [why `let userDetail = this.state.userDetails` is not enough to make a copy.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/1218980)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am setting userDetialsCopy only in componentDidMount and rest of the code I am not changing userDetailsCopy the only thing which I am changing is userDetails. But when userDetails are changes even userDetailsCopy is getting changed.

Comment: You haven't showed how you set it, that is an imporant information

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri apologies, I  have modified the code. Please do help me with a solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is that you think you are making a copy of the object in state by doing this

```
     let userDetail = this.state.userDetails
     userDetail.name = text
```

But, in Javascript, objects are not copied like this, they are passed by referrence. So userDetail at that point contains the referrence to the `userDetails` in your state, and when you mutate the `userDetail` it goes and mutates the one in the state.

ref: https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c

To properly clone the object from the state to your local variable, you need to instead do this:

```
let userDetail = {...this.state.userDetails}

OR

let userDetail = Object.assign({}, this.state.userDetails)
```

Always remember, Objects are passed by referrence not value.

EDIT: I didn't read the question properly, but the above answer is still valid. The reason `userDetailCopy` is being updated too is because `resp.data` is passed by referrence to both of them, and editing any one of them will edit the other.

Comment: I just now tried with your approach and still, userDetailsCopy is getting updated to userDetails.

Comment: Show me the places you have changed them in? Did you use deep cloning in the api call too where you assign `resp.data` to `userDetails` and `userDetailsCopy`

Comment: Yes @Danyal in ComponentDidMount I have assigned resp.data to userDetails and userDetailsCopy. But, I am not making any changes to userDetailsCopy I am just setting the value from API for comparison purpose

Comment: Try setting the resp.data like this and see. 
```this.setState({ 
             userDetails: { ...resp.data },
             userDetailsCopy: { ...resp.data }
})```

Also, you have lots of typos in code, I'm not sure if it's because you have written it here or if it's in your actual code

Comment: :( tried above approach but userDetailsCopy is getting updated.

Comment: That's extremely odd behaviour, unless it's getting changed some other way, because this code should work. Maybe paste the changes here, let's see. I can't really think of any more bugs in this

Comment: I have modified my code in above example. In componentDidMount I have mentioned a sample JSON that resp.data would return

Answer (score 1):

React state and its data should be treated as immutable.

From the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were
>   immutable.

Here are five ways how to treat state as immutable:

**Approach #1: Object.assign and Array.concat**

```
updateValue = (text, index) => {
  const { userDetails } = this.state;

  const userDetail = Object.assign({}, userDetails[index]);

  userDetail.name = text;

  const newUserDetails = []
    .concat(userDetails.slice(0, index))
    .concat(userDetail)
    .concat(userDetails.slice(index + 1));

  this.setState({
    userDetails: newUserDetails
  });
}
```

**Approach #2: Object and Array Spread**

```
updateValue = (text, index) => {
  const { userDetails } = this.state;

  const userDetail = { ...userDetails[index], name: text };

  this.setState({
    userDetails: [
      ...userDetails.slice(0, index),
      userDetail,
      ...userDetails.slice(index + 1)
    ]
  });
}
```

**Approach #3: Immutability Helper**

```js
import update from 'immutability-helper';

updateValue = (text, index) => {
  const userDetails = update(this.state.userDetails, {
    [index]: {
      $merge: {
        name: text
      }
    }
  });

  this.setState({ userDetails });
};
```

**Approach #4: Immutable.js**

```js
import { Map, List } from 'immutable';

updateValue = (text, index) => {
  const userDetails = this.state.userDetails.setIn([index, 'name'], text);

  this.setState({ userDetails });
};
```

**Approach #5: Immer**

```js
import produce from "immer";

updateValue = (text, index) => {
  this.setState(
    produce(draft => {
        draft.userDetails[index].name = text;
    })
  );
};
```

*Note:*
Option #1 and #2 only do a shallow clone. So if your object contains nested objects, those nested objects will be copied by reference instead of by value. So if you change the nested object, you’ll mutate the original object.

To maintain the `userDetailsCopy` unchanged you need to maintain the immutability of `state` (and `state.userDetails` of course).

```js
function getUserDerails() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
    () => resolve([
      { id: 1, name: 'Tom', age : 40 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Jerry', age : 35 }
    ]),
    300
  ));
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userDetails: [],
    userDetailsCopy: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getUserDerails().then(users => this.setState({
      userDetails: users,
      userDetailsCopy: users
    }));
  }
  
  createChangeHandler = userDetailId => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    const { userDetails } = this.state;
    
    const index = userDetails.findIndex(({ id }) => id === userDetailId);
    const userDetail = { ...userDetails[index], name: value };

    this.setState({
      userDetails: [
        ...userDetails.slice(0, index),
        userDetail,
        ...userDetails.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    const { userDetails, userDetailsCopy } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {userDetails.map(userDetail => (
          <input
            key={userDetail.id}
            onChange={this.createChangeHandler(userDetail.id)}
            value={userDetail.name}
          />
        ))}
        
        <pre>userDetails: {JSON.stringify(userDetails)}</pre>
        <pre>userDetailsCopy: {JSON.stringify(userDetailsCopy)}</pre>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```